# Do I have to use EXACTLY the same power cable

Tags: power-supply, speakers, alternatives

I've purchased some surround sound speakers but the jack plug is **L** shaped and won't fit through my speaker stand.
The power supply states it's a **18V 1.3a** but I can't seem to find a power supply like that. Is there an alternative I can use??

Many thanks

Comment: If you choose to go the 'replace the tip' method (which is what I'd do), make sure to get one where the inside 'hole' is same size as the existing one.   There are a few different "standards" for those DC jacks.  It's easy to match the outside diameter, but the inside diameter is a little more tricky.   They only vary by fractions of a millimeter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's 18V, >= 1.3A and has the same plug polarity, you can use it. You can also cut the jack off and put a new one on (or just push the cord through and re-attach it).

If you do cut the end off, I'd recommend using butt-splices (if you can't solder/shrink tubing) to put it back on, or get an end with screw terminals:

[image]

Just pay close attention to the polarity when you reassemble.

Comment: Why someone would downvote this is boggling. +1

Answer (score -1):

> *the jack plug is L shaped and won't fit through my speaker stand*

Presumably a straight jack will work so, get a short adapter cable like this one: -

[image]

Or this one: -

[image]

Comment: These are speaker extensions, not power ones. He'd need one without the multi-terminal jack since these are set up for L/R audio...

Comment: These are just examples - mono ones can be purchased that are suitable for the current and voltage.